# Smarty Variables

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty, template-engine

I'm building a CodeIgniter application and using Smarty as my templating system. Instead of trying to assign Smarty variables from various controllers, would it be better to define all the Smarty variables in one place (e.g. a controller super-class) so that everything is in one place? My concern with this approach is that assigning variables not needed for a particular controller/view pair might degrade performance.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**All in one place != Good**

Keep your template variable assignments by the code that's assigning them. Not only will this be way simpler to maintain, it makes more sense because it should be the controller assigning the template variables directly (not through some intermediary). Also, more than one controller could use a template and they could be assign variables via different rules.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the pros and cons?

Comment: I added some more details. There are no pros to your super-class approach, unfortunately. Having tens or hundreds of variables in one place doesn't serve a good purpose in MVC as the controller methods are in charge of interacting with the models and views, hence, they are only logical place to perform template variable assignments.